# Primitivable and Riemann integrable discontinious function

Tags: riemann-integration, continuity

Are there any known examples of functions that are both Riemann integrable and primitivable (they admit antiderivatives), but not continious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:
$$(x^{2}sin(\frac{1}{x}))^{'}=2xsin(\frac{1}{x})-cos(\frac{1}{x})$$

Comment: Indeed, simply $\cos \frac 1x$, $f(0) = 0$, works.

Comment: yes its more simple as given by me...

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Please elaborate how $\cos \frac 1x$ satisfy the above question? What is the primitive? Why it is R integrable?

Comment: @neelkanth How a discontinuous function has primitive?

Comment: make suitable domain..